# How to get the Generic type for the Jackson ObjectMapper

Tags: java, jackson, type-erasure

Java erases normally the `Generics` data on compilation, but there is a possibility to get that information (the Jackson `ObjectMapper` does that pretty well).

My Problem: I have a Class with a property of List:

```
public class User {
    public List<Long> listProp;//it is public only to keep the example simple
}
```

How can I get the correct `TypeReference` (or `JavaType` ?) so that I can map programatically a JSON String to the correct List Type, having the instance of the `Class` class (User.class) and the property name (listProp)? What I mean is this:

```
TypeReference typeReference = ...;//how to get the typeReference?
List<Long> correctList = om.readValue(jsonEntry.getValue(), typeReference);//this should return a List<Long> and not eg. a List<Integer>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the mappers constructType method?

```
Type genericType = User.class.getField("listProp").getGenericType();
List<Long> correctList = om.readValue(jsonEntry.getValue(), om.constructType(genericType));
```

Answer (score 4):

jackson use TypeReference to construct generic type

```
TypeReference typeReference =new TypeReference<List<Long>>(){}
```

jackson use JavaType to construct generic type

```
JavaType jt = om.getTypeFactory().constructArrayType(Long.class);
```

jackson support three types

1. Class
2. JavaType
3. TypeReference

i like use JavaType, it is more clear for generic type, for normal object use Class

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a less exotic approach to deserializing a generic type is to wrap it inside a concrete type:

```
class ListLongWrapper extends ArrayList<Long> {} // package scope
... or ...
static class ListLongWrapper extends ArrayList<Long> {} // class scope
```

then

```
String jsonStr = objMapper.writeValueAsString(user1.listProp); // serialize
user2.listProp = objMapper.readValue(jsonStr,ListLongWrapper.class); // deserialize
```

*Notice that `extends` requires a class type (here I used `ArrayList`) instead of the interface `List`.*

---

This suggests an even more direct approach for the given example -- `User` is already a wrapper (and `listProp` is `public`):

```
public class User {
    public List<Long> listProp;
}
```

then

```
String jsonStr = objMapper.writeValueAsString(user1); // serialize
var user2 = objMapper.readValue(jsonStr,User.class); // deserialize
```

*In this case, you can use the interface `List` as-is as a field type within the wrapping class, but this means you have no control over the concrete type that Jackson will use.*

Comment: What may be surprising is that nested generic types _just work_.  It's only when the top-level is generic that you have to jump through hoops to define the type for Jackson.